# How to provide IntersectionStrategy in boost::geometry

Tags: boost, intersection, boost-geometry

I need to replace old version of boost (1.58) with a new one (1.66). But there is an issue with a breaking change that happened since then in boost::geometry library. I have little knowledge in this library. In the code that I depend on (not written by me) function self_turns() is used. As far as I understand it calculates self intersections. In previous version it required 4 parameters, but in the new one it requires 5 (plus 2 optional). New parameter is IntersectionStrategy. I searched a lot but failed to find any documentation or examples of how this can be defined/used. Does anyone know how it should be used now?

Comment: We're not psychics. If you can't show the code, we're not going to see what it does/intends/should do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to pass a variable declared like this:

```
typename bg::strategy::intersection::services::default_strategy
   <typename bg::cs_tag<Geometry>::type>::type strategy;
```

(where Geometry is your geometry type, and bg an alias for boost::geometry) as the missing Intersection Strategy

No, there are no samples yet, it is meant to be a public function in the future but currently it is not (and therefore the interface can change indeed).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info. That is what I need.